# How to configure ARR - Application Request Routing - to run both as web server applications and as as a reversed proxy?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have this IIS7.5 with ARR installed on and configured as a reverse proxy to another server which is running IIS7.

On this IIS7.5 I have ASP.NET 4 applications and simple websites installed.

Since configuring a farm on this IIS7.5 running it as a reversed proxy, the local application doesn't run with this error message:

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.
```

Will it be possible to run both local application and routing (reverse proxy) on this IIS7.5 at the same time or should I give up and move the applications to other servers?

Answer (score 0):

Application request routing operates as a server-wide URL-rewriter.

This means that it captures *all* traffic coming to a box.

You can still host an IIS website on the same box, but you need to make sure that ARR leaves the requests for this site alone.

I set this up so that the ARR rule, while still remaining a wildcard `*`, I make sure that part of the match conditions is for requests to my local site to be left alone.

There are a number of conditions you can use to create a `does not match` rule.

Ive used:

`{HTTP_HOSTNAME}` if you are just doing HTTP requests and just want certain domain names to be left alone.

`{SERVER_PORT}` if you're hosting an SSL site and are the only one on the box.

`{LOCAL_ADDR}` if your site sits on a dedicated IP address.

many more.... really you just need to set up rules that exclude your locally hosted website.